# Nginx is Preventing Automatic Favicon Fetching from Flask Server

Tags: nginx, flask, webserver

I am using [Nginx](http://nginx.org) for proxying because I have two Flask web servers on the same computer and ip address. I used Nginx to proxy the data to a different port on the localhost depending on what domain was used. For some reason, Safari and Firefox aren't automatically fetching the favicon when accessing the server through Nginx. I have tried accessing the web server directly, skipping Nginx, and it shows the favicon. Also, I have tried adding the "link" tag in the head and accessing the server through nginx and that also works. Why won't it work automatically?

**Solution:** Use Nginx to serve the file

---

My setup:

## Nginx:

www.domain.com file:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name www.domain.com;

location / {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

blog.domain.com file:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name blog.domain.com;

location / {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4500;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

---

## Flask

Both of the flask servers contain this (they serve the favicon.ico out of the static folder):

```
@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico'))
```

Comment: What does your nginx config look like? Where is your favicon.ico file located? How does Flask serve it?

Comment: Why not let nginx server the file? It's much better at that than Flask is.